# Google webFont API browser compatibility

Tags: html, api, fonts

I was going through this:

http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/

(Which BTW I think is fantastic)

And was wondering how compatible its is with older browsers including IE 6?

Comment: Please dont care about IE6... It's such an outdated browser.

Comment: Not in my country, a lot of businesses still use it. Yeah, I know, it should be banned by law!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [FAQ](http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/faq.html#Browsers_Supported):

> **What browsers are supported?**
>
> The Google Font API is compatible with the following browsers:
>
> - Google Chrome: version 4.249.4+
> - Mozilla Firefox: version: 3.5+
> - Apple Safari: version 3.1+
> - Opera: version 10.5+
> - Microsoft Internet Explorer: version 6+
>
> The Google Font API is not currently supported on iPhone, iPad, iPod, or Android.

So yes, you can indeed use this with IE6.